# Data not getting fetched and displayed from firebase real time database to angular 6

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular6, angularfire2

I am new to angular and firebase. I am following Mosh's tutorial of building oshop using angular.
I am stuck at the admin-products page where I am not able to fetch the product list and show in admin-products page. I am using Angular6.

**admin-products.component.ts**

```
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit {
   products$;

   constructor(
    private productService: ProductService) {
      this.products$ = this.productService.getAll();
    }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**product.service.ts**

```
    export class ProductService {

      constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase) { }

    create(product){
      this.db.list('/product').push(product);
    }

    getAll() {
        return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
            map(productDb => 
                { productDb.map ( prod => {
                  return { 
                          key: prod.key, 
                          data: prod.payload.val()
                          }
                })}
              )
             )

    }
    /* *I also tried below options but nothing works for me.*
    getAll(){
      return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges();
    }

    getAll(){
      return this.db
      .list('/products') /*reference => reference.orderByChild('name')) 
          .snapshotChanges() // include snapshot itself (access to key property)
          .pipe(map(metadata => metadata.map(data => ({ key: data.payload.key, data: data.payload.val() }))));
    } 

    getAll(){
      return this.db.list('/products').valueChanges();


    }*/

    }
```

**admin-products.component.html**

```
<tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let p of products$  ">

         <td> {{ p.key }} </td>
         <td> {{ p.data }} </td> 

         <td>
            <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/', p.key]">Edit</a>
         </td> 
     </tr> 
 </tbody>
```

What I get on the admin-product page is an empty table with just the header.

Please suggest.

Comment: I think you're missing a `return` here: `{ productDb.map ( prod => {`. Shouldn't that be `{ return productDb.map ( prod => {`?

Comment: I updated my code as below and it worked:

getAll(){
  return this.db.list('/product')
  .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
      map((productDb) => {
          return productDb.map((productDB) => ({
              key: productDb.key,
              val: productDb.payload.val(),
          }));
      }));     

}
and updated html as
<tbody>
     <tr *ngFor="let p of products$ | async  ">
        
         <td> {{ p.val.title }} </td>
         <td> {{ p.val.price }} </td> 
       
         <td>
            <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/', p.key]">Edit</a>

Comment: Good to hear that you got it working Aks!